# Unable to delete database file after closing UCanAccess connection

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I used UCanAccess to connect to temporary Access files for reading data, after which I want to delete these temporary files. However, I always get `file.delete()=false`.

Here is my code

```
public class JAccess {
    static Connection conn;
    static Statement stat;

    public static void connect(String DBFilename) {
        try {used ucanaccess to connect temporary access files
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            String DataSource = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBFilename;
            String user = "user";
            String pw = "pw";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DataSource, user, pw);
            stat = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void disconnect() {
       try {
            stat.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        stat = null;
        conn = null;
    }
}


public void SelectTable(String DBFilename) throws SQLException {
    JAccess.connect(DBFilename);
    JAccess.disconnect();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
.........
    SelectTable(DBFilename);
    File f = new File(DBFilename);
    f.delete();
```

Why is `f.delete()` failing?

Comment: Try appending `;immediatelyReleaseResources=true` to the end of your connection URL.

Comment: Itamar , thanks for your modify.
Gord , thank for your answer , I will try it at monday.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks Gord Thompson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, UCanAccess opens a connection to the database file with `immediatelyReleaseResources=false`. Under those circumstances, when the `java.sql.Connection` is closed UCanAccess will actually keep the file handle and HSQLDB resources open for a brief period of time in case the application wants to re-establish a connection to the database. For example, this might happen with an ORM that opens and closes database connections for every operation. However, it also means that a temporary database file cannot be deleted right after the connection is closed because UCanAccess still has the file open.

If we specify `immediatelyReleaseResources=true` in the connection URL then UCanAccess will close the file handle and release the HSQLDB resources as soon as possible after the `java.sql.Connection` is closed. This is often the preferred behaviour for ETL jobs and other tasks that require a "one-shot" connection to a database file.